# Vue Watch Handler not triggerring on Zero Value

Tags: javascript, select, vue.js, vue-reactivity

I have the following code for a dropdown element. The options for the dropdown element are loaded from a database, and that works correctly.

Every element fires the watch handler fine except for the one that has a value of zero. I see that the element itself has the Vue get/set reactive properties, but my watch handler refuses to fire when selecting the dropdown option with a zero value. I need to keep it at a zero value unless it absolutely cannot be done as zero indicates an aggregation of all data in our database system made for this application. Having to change it from zero would result in changes in other systems as well. Any insights as to why the zero value isn't firing the watch handler?

`.select-site
                p Active Site:
                select(v-model='selectedSite')
                    option(v-for='option in options', v-bind:value='option.value')
                        | {{ option.text }}`

```
let dataStore = new Vue({
  data: {
    selectedSchoolValue: '',
    schoolSites: [{
      text: 'Select a School',
      value: '',
      default: 1,
    }]
  },
  watch: {

    selectedSchoolValue(newSelectedSchool, oldValue) {

      if (newSelectedSchool !== oldValue) {

        topbarVM.selectedSite = newSelectedSchool;

        if (pageVM) {
          pageVM.selectedSite = newSelectedSchool;
        }

        if (newSelectedSchool) {
          document.cookie = `schoolSelectValue=${ newSelectedSchool };path=/`;
        }

      }

      if (typeof loadVizData === 'function') {
        loadVizData();
      }

    }

  }
});

/*Populates school list from DB*/
const getSchoolsForSelect = (callback = null) => {

  let self = dataStore;

  GetSchools({}, (schools) => {

    if (schools.status === 400) {
      return location.href = "/login?message=Your%20session%20expired,%20please%20log%20in%20again.";
    }


    // strip trailing whitespace
    schools.forEach((el) => {
      el.schoolName = el.schoolName.trim();
    });

    // sort by alpha ascending on schoolName, except
    // the District (siteId 70) should be forced to the top
    schools.sort(function(a, b) {
      if (b.siteId === 70)
        return 1;

      if (a.schoolName < b.schoolName || (a.siteId === 70 || b.siteId === 70))
        return -1;

      if (a.schoolName > b.schoolName)
        return 1;

      return 0;
    });

    // sort schools by schoolName, but force district to the top
    // of the select (array element zero)

    schools.forEach((el) => {

      /*self.schoolSites.push({
          text: el.schoolName,
          value: el.siteId,
      });*/

      //below does not work. Vue Watcher for dropdown does not fire when the zero value is selected.

      //force school 70 (district) to Id value 0 to match indicator system. Easier to do on front-end
      if (el.siteId === 70) {
        self.schoolSites.push({
          text: el.schoolName,
          value: 0
        });
      } else {
        self.schoolSites.push({
          text: el.schoolName,
          value: el.siteId,
        });
      }

    });

    callback && callback();

  });

};
```

Comment: What does your dropdown look like? How are methods from the ViewModel being bound to it? How does it change the value of `selectedSchoolValue`? What does the `selectedSchoolValue` look like? Are you sure the watcher is not running, is it only the expected side effects of the watcher not occurring (the watcher is running but not in the expected way), how have you verified this?

Comment: @wing Using the Vue DevTools extension, I've checked to see that selectedSite is in fact changing to 0. I set a breakpoint on the watcher and verified that it fires on every selectedSite change except for the option that has value 0. I've updated to show my dropdown and binding.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying select with watcher and I see no problem...

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    options: [
      {id: 0, name: 'Please select...'},
      {id: 1, name: 'Option 1'},
      {id: 2, name: 'Option 2'},
      {id: 3, name: 'Option 3'},
    ],
    selected: 0
  },
  watch: {
    selected (n, o) {
      console.log(n, o)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <select v-model="selected">
    <option v-for="{id, name} in options" :value="id">
      {{ name }}
    </option>
  </select>
  
  <p>You select the option: {{ selected }}</p>
</div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.9/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I tried this with adding an element of {id: 0, name: 'Option 0'} and it works as well. There must be something conflicting or stopping this from happening in my code. I'm not sure exactly what it could be though since I'm loading the options at the same time and exactly the same way.